# How to color every 4th line with Perl?

Tags: perl

To track the lines of console output better, I'd like to color every 4th line.
So I'd like to pipe my output through `perl -ne`. I don't know much perl, but I have the feeling there must be a concise way to do that?

What is the shortest way to achieve that?

Comment: Is this on WIndows or Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [`Term::ANSIColor`](https://p3rl.org/Term::ANSIColor) module, but to get the output of a program to appear like that you will have to modify the program or write a filter

Something like this perhaps

```
$ cat prog.pl | perl -MTerm::ANSIColor -ne 'print $. % 4 ? $_ : color("bold red").$_.color("reset")'
```

On Windows you would need to use [`CMD::Colors`](https://p3rl.org/CMD::Colors) like this

```
> type prog.pl | perl -MCMD::Colors -nE"$.%4 ? print : Cprint($_, 'red', undef, 'bold')"
```

Comment: add -l to avoid having your newlines colored.  yes, I know that won't make a visible difference, but it feels cleaner to me to have the reset on the same line as added the color.

Comment: @ysth: I understand you completely, but that makes it minimally slower just to preserve your feelings. I'll leave your comment to stand for itself. And thank you for being one of the *sensitive ones*! I'm most upset about needing a different module depending on the platform, but that's big business I guess. The documentation for `CMD::Colors` hints that is uses the same ANSI escape sequences, so I will see if I can write something that's more universal

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [colorgcc](https://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html) for an example of how to write a filter to color the output of a program.